# How to add X.509 v.3 google certificate to project with Bouncy Castle in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, x509certificate2, service-accounts

I have been trying to use Google's service account on Xamarin.iOS. System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates is not supported for PCL projects so i need a different way(like Bouncy Castle or PCLCrypto) to load X509Certificate into the project. Basically, as in the Google's document, the way of extracting the certificate is as following:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

The question is that, what is the alternative way of loading certificate(the first line of the code) in Bouncy Castle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Target of your PCL project to .NETStandard. After this,

> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

is supported.

You can do it with the following steps:

1. Right-click on your PCL project
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on Library
4. Click on Target .NET Platform Standard
5. Accept
6. Goto project.json and add: `"netstandard1.3": { "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"}`
7. Add your Nuget package.

For step 4 you must remove all your Nuget packages and after step 6 you must reinstall their.